# Ionic Changes Content-Type

Tags: ionic-framework

Ok I have to make a simple GET request that work in Postman but not in the Ionic code. I have determined that the reason is that the API treats incoming requests differently based on Content-Type. application/json works text doesn't.

```
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      "Accept": 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    },
```

As you can see I'm setting the header to try to force application/json but when I sniff the request it has changed to text/html somehow. How do I force Ionic to take my Content-Type as definitive?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work with the following headers

```
var headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
};
```